# Change SVG image color on hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm going straight to the "problem". I have an SVG map which represents Portugal. So what i want is: When I hover over a district (Ex. Lisbon) it changes color. Right now all the districts are grey, and I want them to be orange only when I hover over them.

I thought about connecting/calling a css file to run the `a:hover{color: orange;}` code for each on of the districts. However, it did not work.
Why can't I use a `<style>` inside of a `<path>`?

Right now I've got this code on my "Portugal.svg":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet idhref="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>
<html>
<svg

   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   baseprofile="tiny"
   height="435.27365"
   version="1.2"
   viewbox="0 0 1000 597"
   width="431.70035"
   id="svg25"
   sodipodi:docname="Portugal.svg"
   style="fill:#7c7c7c;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"
   inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371"
   xmlns:style="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/mystyle.css">

  <a xlink:href="http://www.artiroots.pt/devel-230b433e/wordpress/?s=Setubal">
        <title>Setúbal</title>
        <g>
        <path

            d="259......."
            id="P....."
            name="Setúbal"
            fill="#7c7c7c"
            inkscape:connector-curvature="0" 
            style="stroke-width: 0.100"
        />
        </g>
  </a>
</svg>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: _“I'm having much problem with this, i've searched a lot, but idk what to do.”_ - that is not a good basis to work on here. First of all, please go read [ask]. And then tell us what your research has turned up (no, that can’t be “nothing”), and what you have tried with which results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG and HTML are not so differents, so you can treat them on a similar way.

The first thing I see on your markup is that you have the fill attribute embed on the SVG code, if you want to change the color only using CSS you are going to use important! It would be better if you style the svg using CSS, then you could use the pseudo class "hover" to change the color.

```css
path {
  fill: #ccc;
}

path:hover {
  
  fill: tomato;
}
```

```html
<svg id="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000.45 494.44">
<title>map_svg</title>
<g id="test-circle" class="cls-2">
<path d="M 100, 100 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0"/>
</g></svg>
```

Comment: So I must create a example.css file. Right? So that I can insert the `path{fill:#ccc;}.....`. Or should I insert it right into the svg file?

Comment: It would be the recommended way, but if you only need it for this you can put it on the same page, surrounded by style tags.